# Adding an object to the end of the circular list

Tags: java, nodes, circular-list

I have a working code here which adds a new node to the end. but for some reason after adding the third node, the first node disappears.

This is the method

```
public boolean add(Token obj)  {

    if(obj == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (head == null){
        head = new Node(null, null, obj);
        return true;
    }

    while (head.next != null){
        head = head.next;
    }
    head.next = new Node(null,null,obj); // Next, Previous , Object

    return true;

}
```

with creating a new node this

and when i call it from main like this

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    CircularList test = new CircularList();

    Token something = new Token("+");
    test.add(something);
    test.add(new Token(2));
    test.add(new Token(5));



    System.out.println(test.toString());


}
```

}

and my output is

"List contains 2 , 5 "

So if i delete the third add new token ie Token(5), the first one comes back up.

Any help on this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (head.next != null){
    head = head.next;
}
```

It's wrong.U change the head pointer..

```
Node temp=head;
while(temp.next!=null)
    temp=temp.next
temp.next=new Node(null,null,obj);
```